# what is going wrong with this query/need to check today date greater than date?

Tags: postgresql

```
$query = 'SELECT distinct a.indent_req_id,b.id,b.approval_status,b.date,c.department from tra_dt a join tra_head b on b.id = a.indent_req_id join mas_dep c on b.req_dpt_id = c.dept_id where b.approval_status = "a"  and cast(("exp_date")as date) >= " cast('.$now. 'as date)"';
```

> operator does not exist: character varying = tra_dt LINE 1
>
> a.exp_date = character varying;
>
> even tried with now() function no luck still.
>   help me!here  here a.exp_date is character varying;

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `b.approval_status = "a"` should probably be `b.approval_status = 'a'` (ie single quotes for strings)

Comment: @matt:error;msg;operator does not exist: character varying = tra_dt LINE 1

Comment: Try `SELECT distinct a.indent_req_id,b.id,b.approval_status,b.date,c.department 
from tra_dt a join tra_head b on b.id = a.indent_req_id join mas_dep c on b.req_dpt_id = c.dept_id 
where b.approval_status = 'a' and cast(("exp_date")as date) >= now()::date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT distinct a.exp_date, a.indent_req_id,b.id,b.approval_status,b.date,c.department from tra_dt a 
join tra_head b on b.id = a.indent_req_id 
join mas_dep c on b.req_dpt_id = c.dept_id where b.approval_status = 'a'  and exp_date  >=  '$now'"
```